# select query store value in text box ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

this is my code which store the value into the "test" combobox but i want to store it in "test" textbox

```
Dim text3 As String
Dim text4 As String

Dim sql As String


Size_1.SetFocus
text3 = Size_1.text
Order_1_Company.SetFocus
text4 = Order_1_Company.text



sql = " SELECT S_Rate from Stock_T where S_Size = '" + text3 + "' And S_Company_Name = '" + text4 + "'"

test.RowSource = ""

test.RowSource = sql
```

Comment: How can you have two controls of same name on form: "test" combobox and "test" textbox? Please clearly explain what you want. to do. Are you trying to return the value of SQL query in textbox?

Comment: i will change this "test" combobox to textbox & i want to return the value into text box

Answer (score 2):

Don't reference Text property, should be Value but since Value is default don't need to reference. Use `&` character for concatenation.

Could open a recordset to retrieve related data but since you want only one value, following methods are simpler.

Use DLookup():
`=DLookup("S_Rate", "Stock_T", "S_Size='" & text3 & "' AND S_Company_Name ='" & text4 & "'"`

However, usually a better approach is to include the lookup field in combobox RowSource then refer to that field by its column index. Column index begins with zero:
`=[comboboxName].Column(2)`

And another is to include lookup table in form RecordSource and bind textbox to field. Set textbox as Locked Yes and TabStop No.

If desire is to save looked up value, then use code - VBA or macro. Use one of the above methods to display the rate in an unbound textbox so users can see it during data entry. Then use code in some event (most likely form BeforeUpdate) to save. VBA example:
`Me!S_Rate = Me.textboxname`

Comment: Thanks man .. it works ..  i have one more question .. can i store the value of this Dlookup text box value..?

Comment: See revised answer. If this resolves issue, please mark accepted.